# how to set button text to "clicked" using setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a problem with my code. I have created a code that can trigger which button has been clicked. I can write the execution code but the problem is I want to change get the Id of that button and change the button text.
My code:

```
package com.example.tic;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView playerStatus;
    Button btn_0 , btn_1 , btn_2 , btn_3 ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        playerStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playerStatus);
        btn_0 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_0);
        btn_1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
        btn_2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
        btn_3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_3);

        btn_0.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_3.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      //Execution code

        }
    }
```

//////////////
In the execution code I want to set the text of the button as "clicked" on clicking of any button`enter code here`

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what are you trying to achieve. I don't understand what your " I want to change get the Id of that button" means?

Comment: @SlothCoding basically i have four buttons.I want that when a button has been clicked,the text of that button will turn into "clicked".

Comment: You just got your answer below, you can use that. If you want different action for each button you can use switch(v.getId()) and just do case: R.id.btn1 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that, you are using the View.OnClickListener implementation for every button.

This is not a real problem.

Use this code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
   switch(v.getId()){
     case R.id.btn_0: {
     //do something: e.g setting text to clicked
       ((Button)v).setText("Clicked");
       break;
     }
     case R.id.btn_1: {
       ((Button)v).setText("Clicked");
       break;
     }
case R.id.btn_2: {
    
       ((Button)v).setText("Clicked");
       break;
     }
case R.id.btn_3: {
       ((Button)v).setText("Clicked");
       break;
     }
}
}
```

As you know, you can replace the repeating 'case-codes' with wrapping them:

```
switch(v.getId()){
 case R.id.btn_0:
 case R.id.btn_1:{
 //do something... setting the text...
 break;
 }
 case R.id.btn_2:{
 //do something else
 break;
 }
}
```

The following codes are only needed if you want to distinguish between the actions for the different buttons.

If you just want to set "clicked" as text to every button, you can just do this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
((Button)v).setText("clicked");
}
```

Comment: Stop it please!

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Execution code
    if (v instanceof Button){
         ((Button) v).setText("clicked");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an if-else statement in your onClick method and check which button was clicked with .getSource and then change the text with .setText().